# Dialog boxes are not created WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog

If I create a child window (In this case window "About") to the main window, the dialog box for some reason is not called. If you do not the child window is a dialog box called normal and works fine. GetLastError returns the error number 1812 (The specified image file did not contain a resource section.). But from a resource file everything is fine. And as I said, if you do not create a child window then everything works fine. What's the problem?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

LONG WINAPI WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM,LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
LRESULT CALLBACK PointsProc(HWND hPoints, UINT message, WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam);

HINSTANCE hInst;
HWND hPoints;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    hInst = hInstance;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS w;
    memset(&w,0,sizeof(WNDCLASS));
    w.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    w.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    w.hInstance = hInstance;
    w.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    w.lpszClassName = L"My Class";
    RegisterClass(&w);
    hwnd = CreateWindow(L"My Class", L"My title", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    300, 200, 200, 180, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    HMENU main_menu = CreateMenu();
    AppendMenu(main_menu, MF_STRING, 1111, L"Box");

    WNDCLASS w2;
    memset(&w2, 0, sizeof(WNDCLASS));
    w2.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)PointsProc;
    w2.hInstance = hInst;
    w2.lpszClassName = L"About";
    w2.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW); 
    w2.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(111, 111, 111));
    RegisterClass(&w2);

    hPoints = CreateWindowEx(0, L"About", (LPCTSTR) NULL,
    WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE | WS_DISABLED, 10, 10,
    100, 100, hwnd, (HMENU)1112, hInst, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hPoints,SW_NORMAL);
    UpdateWindow(hPoints);

    SetMenu(hwnd, main_menu);

    ShowWindow(hwnd,nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}

LONG WINAPI WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (Message)
    {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(LOWORD(wparam)) 
            {
                case 1111:
                    DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), hwnd, About);
                    return 0;
            }
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY: 
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wparam, lparam);
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK PointsProc(HWND hPoints, UINT message, WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{   
    switch(message)
    {   
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        case WM_PAINT:
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hPoints, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
            {
                EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
                return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
            }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialog box **is** called, only it takes a long time because `PointsProc()` is looping...

The problem was the `break;` while handling `WM_PAINT` in `PointsProc()` -- it then skips calling `DefWindowProc()`, so the window keeps getting WM_PAINT messages because the window remains invalid.

```
//        case WM_PAINT:
//            break;
```